# MongoDB .find problems NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I attempt the code below, I just get an empty return from MongoDB....

```
let express = require('express');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let cors = require('cors');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    name: {
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
    },
    email: String,
    employeeID: String
});

const testModel = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('Connected to Mongo');
});

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());

const port = 5000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('connected to port ' + port);
});

testModel.find({}).exec(function(err, res){
    if (!err) {
        console.log(res);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
})
```

BUT, when I use this code, it returns the data I'm looking for..... why?! Every other tutorial I have seen operates like the above.

```
let express = require('express');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let cors = require('cors');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    name: {
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
    },
    email: String,
    employeeID: String
});

const testModel = mongoose.model('test', testSchema, 'test');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('Connected to Mongo');
});

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());

const port = 5000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('connected to port ' + port);
});

testModel.find({}).exec(function(err, res){
    if (!err) {
        console.log(res);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
})
```

How can I fix this in my code, or is it something within Mongo updates that this is a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

By default, mongoose pluralizes the name of the model when you call [mongoose.model()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model) to determine the collection name. In your first example, it will be looking in the `tests` collection for documents.

In the second example, you specify that the name of the collection should be `test` , which is why the behavior is different.